# Can someone explain in simple terms what equity means?

Tags: nlhe, poker-strategy, equity, fold-equity

I've seen examples where commentators mention that he has a good equity to make a call.
I do understand what poker odds are.

Can some one give a simple example to help understand what equity/fold-equity is?
*Explain it to me like I'm a 5 year old.*

Answer (score 4):

Equity is simply how much of the pot is "yours" based on your odds to win it. If there's $100 in the pot, and you have a 50% chance of winning it, then you have $50 in equity. If you have a 30% chance to win it, you have $30 in equity.

For a final call on the river, that's your only concern. Let's say the pot is $100, and your opponent bets $100 all-in, and you have to call. Well, there's $200 out on the table. If you think your odds of winning are greater than 50%, then your equity is more than $100, so calling $100 is a good deal. If you think your odds are less, then you should fold.